# Why do the queries take the same time to get data even though the number of rows is very different?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have 29,938,766 rows inside the VISITS table and the table looks like this

| USER_ID (INT) | VISITED_IN (DATETIME) |
| --- | --- |
| 65 | 2020-08-26 07:57:43 |
| 1182 | 2019-03-15 02:46:48 |
| 1564 | 2015-07-04 10:59:44 |
| 73 | 2021-03-18 00:25:08 |
| 3791 | 2017-10-17 12:22:45 |
| 51 | 2022-05-02 19:11:09 |
| 917 | 2017-11-20 15:32:06 |
| 3 | 2019-12-29 15:15:51 |
| 51 | 2015-02-08 17:48:30 |
| 1531 | 2020-08-05 08:44:55 |
| Etc... | Etc... |

When running this query, It takes 17-20 seconds and returns 63,514 (The user has 63,514 visits)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 917
```

When running this query, It takes 17-20 seconds and returns 193 (The user has 193 visits)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 716
```

The problem is the query always takes between 17-20 seconds for 29,938,766 rows even if the user has only 3, 50, 70, or 1,000,000 visits.

I think the problem is because it is looping for all rows?

The second query must be faster than the first query. It depends on the number of rows. But both queries take the same time!

What do you suggest to me to avoid this problem?

---

**Table structure**

[image]

[image]

---

**Update: Here is a new suggested scenario:**

When a user enters his or others' profile, He can see the number of profile visits and he can filter visits using this way

```
Last 24 hours
|
---> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 5 AND VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

Last 7 days
|
---> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 5 AND VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);

Last 30 days
|
---> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISITS WHERE USER_ID = 5 AND VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);

All time
|
---> SELECT VISITS FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = 5;
```

Also, I'll create a recurring event that executes this command every day.

```
DELETE FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Also, I'll make sure to increase the VISITS column when adding a new row in the VISITS table.

```
UPDATE USERS SET VISITS = VISITS + 1 WHERE ID = 5
```

Comment: Where is CREATE TABLE script of your table? Your short description is not enough.

Comment: *I think the problem is because it is looping for all rows?* If you have no any index where `USER_ID` is an expression prefix than this is correct.

Comment: @Akina `Where is CREATE TABLE script of your table? Your short description is not enough.` Do you mean you want the command when I created the VISITS table? Yes? I created it manually in phpMyAdmin and check the table structure in the image above

Comment: Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE visits;` and provide complete output.

Comment: General suggestion is `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON visits (user_id) ALGORITHM = INPLACE;` but the indexing may be long and may decrease your system performance. If you may to stop your server for some time then I'd define `(user_id, visited_in)` as primary key instead (this will be long). Anycase try to test previously on separate database with complete data copy (for example, restore your backup on developer testserver or on your local workstation).

Comment: @Akina I don't know how other websites store views or visitors in the table and that table can be reached in billions of rows.

Comment: @Akina Inside my app, I allow the user to see how many people visit his profile last 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days, 12 months, or All time. I can go with the simple solution by creating a column inside the Users table but that will show the number of visits without dates. If you have any other way to do that please tell me, Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: I can say nothing, this is practice question. You must test. For new suggested scenario the composite index is more preferrable. You may create common index, not primary key as I have told above (but this will increase the disk size consumption twice). Also you may not delete rows but partition the table by the year_month, or at least you may investigate this recommendation applicability.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INDEX(user_id, visited_in)
```

will speed up all the `SELECTs` you mentioned.  They will have to scan a chunk of the index; they will not have to "scan the whole table".

The `DELETE` needs `INDEX(visited_in).  But it is problematic if you don't run it frequently enough.  This is because Deleting thousands of rows at one time is potentially a problem.  Consider running that delete at least once an hour.

If the table will be really big, etc, consider using Partitioning of a "time series".  With that `DROP PARTITION`, is *much* faster.  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Any caching service will provide stale counts, but it will be faster some of the time.

It is "ok to hit the database every time someone opens a page", but only if the queries are efficient enough.  Do Index.

In my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394975/18753735) to your other Question, I explain how a Summary table can speed things up even more.  However it assumes "last N days" is measured from midnight to midnight.  Your current queries are `NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY`.  That is messier to implement than midnight.  Are you willing to change the meaning of "last N days"?

(Some INDEX basics...)

An important reason for any index is its ability to rapidly find the row(s) based on some column(s).

- An `INDEX` is a list of keys mapping to rows.
- A `UNIQUE INDEX` is an `INDEX`, plus a uniqueness constraint -- implying that no two rows have the same value in the index.
- The one and only `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index designated to uniquely identify every row in the table.

"key" and "index" are synonyms.

Indexes (in MySQL's InnoDB engine) are implemented as a BTree (actually a B+Tree; see Wikipedia).  In the case of the PK, the rest of the columns are sitting there with the PK value.  In the case of "secondary" keys, the 'value' part of the BTree is the PK column(s).

Any index can contain 1 column or multiple columns (called "composite")

`INDEX(lastname)` is not likely to be UNIQUE
`INDEX(lastname, firstname)` is still not likely to be UNIQUE, but it is "composite".

Comment: See if the section I added helps.