# How can I count the visits according to the date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause, conditional-aggregation

**The VISITS table**

| USER_ID | VISITED_IN |
| --- | --- |
| 518 | 2022-04-13 20:37:04 |
| 518 | 2021-12-29 22:26:50 |
| 518 | 2021-03-04 04:22:46 |
| 518 | 2021-08-13 02:14:54 |
| 518 | 2022-05-26 20:49:01 |
| 518 | 2022-05-05 17:47:46 |
| 518 | 2021-09-12 08:58:33 |
| 518 | 2021-04-07 18:36:59 |
| 518 | 2021-06-14 04:47:52 |
| 518 | 2021-12-26 22:16:47 |

Let's suppose the current time is `28-5-2022 15:00:00`, I'm trying to filter the visits by the date.

**The expected result when executing the command**

| LAST_60_MINUTES | LAST_24_HOURS | LAST_7_DAYS | LAST_30_DAYS | LAST_6_MONTHS | LAST_12_MONTHS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 8 |

**Here is what I tried but does not work as I want**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))) AS LAST_24_HOURS,
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
    COUNT((SELECT USER_ID FROM VISITS WHERE VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH))) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
    FROM VISITS WHERE
    USER_ID = 518
```

For more information look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420927/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-millions-of-rows-inside-the-visits-table)

Comment: A Summary table (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72426694/1766831) would work nicely if your titles were "last 60 min", "earlier today", "week ending yesterday", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_24_HOURS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
FROM VISITS 
WHERE USER_ID = 518;
```

or `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)) AS LAST_60_MINUTES,
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) AS LAST_24_HOURS,
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS LAST_7_DAYS,
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS LAST_30_DAYS,
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS LAST_6_MONTHS,
    SUM(VISITED_IN >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) AS LAST_12_MONTHS
FROM VISITS 
WHERE USER_ID = 518;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4bb2a399a96a2049decdfd0c1dfb2fc).

Comment: The query is very very slow, Can you check the link in the question above?

Comment: @luq891 what about that question? You accepted an answer there which means that the performance problem is solved. My answer is about the current question.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved, But when I run your command, The query take a lot of time I don't know why. I will find the problem and tell you.

Comment: Why you put THEN 1?

Comment: @luq891 COUNT() counts any non-null value, so it makes no difference if there is THEN 1 or THEN 2 or even THEN 0, as long as that value (which is returned by the CASE expression) is not null.

Comment: Try to create an index for 'VISITED_IN" as descending, and also for User_ID

Comment: "very slow" -- Do you have specifically this composite index?  `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, visited_in)`?  `DESC` is not critical.

Comment: @SatsaraGunaratne - separate indexes are not useful.  A composite index is what is needed here.

Comment: @RickJames Good morning, Could you look at [this image](https://ibb.co/yd8XZC0)? I created a composite index (USER_ID, VISITED_IN), I know the index is good if there is a where clause, But the command in this answer does not contain a where clause for VISITED_IN, Should I remove the composite index and convert it to a single index with (USER_ID)?

Comment: @luq891 - `INDEX(user_id, visited_id)` can handle any needs for `INDEX(user_id)`.  So, do not add that single-column index.  (That image does not load for me.)

Comment: @RickJames [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9QrZ.png). Sorry, I did not understand you well, If I remove the VISITED_IN and convert it to a single index (USER_ID), Does that will affect the query time because there is no a where clause in the command above?

Comment: A "covering" index is one where _all_ the needed columns (anywhere in the `SELECT`) are in a single `INDEX`.  This is 'somewhat' faster because all the work can be in the BTree containing the `INDEX`, without having to reach over to the data's BTree to get more columns.